# change formatting in DateTime.Parse()

Tags: c#

In the database dates saves in the following format:
 `year-month-day hour:minute:second:msecond`

In the application user can filter grid and in the filter column write the following:
 `08-11` - it's mean 8 November.
I have the following code:

```
var test = DateTime.Parse(filter.SearchingValue);
```

in the `test` variable contains `11.08.2012`. But, I want to get `08.11.2012`.

Comment: Use `ParseExact` and supply a pattern.

Comment: `11 != October`

Comment: In your database, you should be using `DATETIME` columns to save your dates - if you have a _format_ they are saved with, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
string value = string.Format("{0}-{1}"
    , filter.SearchingValue
    , DateTime.Today.Year);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Yes, but also user can split dates by dot: 08.11. More
>   exampple:08.11.12, 08.11, 08-11, 08-11-12.

Maybe there's something easier but this works:

```
// sample input
var inputs = new string[] { "08.11.12", "08.11", "08-11", "08-11-12" };
// possible formats
var formats = new string[] { "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy" };
// try to parse all your sample data
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
{
    string input = inputs[i];
    var tokens = input.Split(new[] { '-', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
    {
        input = string.Format("{0}-{1}"
                , input
                , DateTime.Today.Year);
    }
    else if (tokens.Length == 3)
    {
        string year = tokens[2];
        if (year.Length != 4)
        { 
            year = string.Format("{0:20##}", int.Parse(year));
        }
        input = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}"
                , tokens[0]
                , tokens[1]
                , year);
    }
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid DateTime", "filter.SearchingValue");

    DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (string format in formats)
    {
        bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            input
            , format
            , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            , DateTimeStyles.None
            , out dt);
        if (success) break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
}
```

Comment: if user write the following: `08-11-2012`. This is just filter row.

Comment: @user1260827: I don't understand your last comment. If the user also can enter the year, you need to split the string into parts(f.e. via `String.Split('-')`) and check if it contains a year or not.

Comment: Yes, but also user can split dates by dot: `08.11`. More exampple:`08.11.12`, `08.11`, `08-11`, `08-11-12`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ftest = test.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default date format in your web config, in system.web:

<`globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />`